# Tomcat in Eclipse - HTTP Status 404 requested resource is not available

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, tomcat

I'm about to lose my mind.

I'm following the tutorial here

[Java servlet tutorial for beginners](http://o7planning.org/web/fe/default/en/document/12760/java-servlet-tutorial-for-beginners)

I have this index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And the `web.xml`file

[image]

Both files are in the WebContent folder

I can run Tomcat without problems and

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

works fine but when I run the application or go to

```
http://localhost:8080/ServletTutorial/
```

or

```
http://localhost:8080/ServletTutorial/index.html
```

it gives 404 error requested resource is not available.

I've already configured Tomcat to use Tomcat installation.

I'm about to break into tears... I've been stuck here for two days :(

```
mag 11, 2016 11:57:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
mag 11, 2016 11:57:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Server built:          Mar 18 2016 20:31:49 UTC
mag 11, 2016 11:57:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Server number:         8.0.33.0
mag 11, 2016 11:57:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: OS Name:               Windows 10
mag 11, 2016 11:57:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: OS Version:            10.0
mag 11, 2016 11:57:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Architecture:          x86
mag 11, 2016 11:57:20 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Java Home:             C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91
mag 11, 2016 11:57:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: JVM Version:           1.8.0_91-b14
mag 11, 2016 11:57:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
mag 11, 2016 11:57:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
mag 11, 2016 11:57:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
mag 11, 2016 11:57:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
mag 11, 2016 11:57:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
mag 11, 2016 11:57:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\wtpwebapps
mag 11, 2016 11:57:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\endorsed
mag 11, 2016 11:57:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAZIONI: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
mag 11, 2016 11:57:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMAZIONI: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_91/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_91/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_91/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Antonio\Desktop\eclipse;;.
mag 11, 2016 11:57:21 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAZIONI: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
mag 11, 2016 11:57:21 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAZIONI: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
mag 11, 2016 11:57:21 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAZIONI: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
mag 11, 2016 11:57:21 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAZIONI: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
mag 11, 2016 11:57:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAZIONI: Initialization processed in 1246 ms
mag 11, 2016 11:57:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAZIONI: Starting service Catalina
mag 11, 2016 11:57:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAZIONI: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.33
mag 11, 2016 11:57:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAZIONI: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\docs
mag 11, 2016 11:57:22 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFORMAZIONI: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [224] milliseconds.
mag 11, 2016 11:57:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAZIONI: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\docs has finished in 730 ms
mag 11, 2016 11:57:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAZIONI: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\examples
mag 11, 2016 11:57:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAZIONI: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
mag 11, 2016 11:57:23 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAZIONI: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
mag 11, 2016 11:57:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAZIONI: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\examples has finished in 857 ms
mag 11, 2016 11:57:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAZIONI: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\host-manager
mag 11, 2016 11:57:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAZIONI: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\host-manager has finished in 57 ms
mag 11, 2016 11:57:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAZIONI: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\manager
mag 11, 2016 11:57:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAZIONI: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\manager has finished in 62 ms
mag 11, 2016 11:57:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAZIONI: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT
mag 11, 2016 11:57:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFORMAZIONI: Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\webapps\ROOT has finished in 31 ms
mag 11, 2016 11:57:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAZIONI: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
mag 11, 2016 11:57:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAZIONI: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
mag 11, 2016 11:57:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMAZIONI: Server startup in 1834 ms
```

Comment: Both files are in the WebContent folder - actually the web.xml must be in WebContent/WEB-INF folder.

Comment: I'm trying to enter the xml file code but it doesn't allow me 0_o

Comment: Didn't get the last comment. Is there any error?

Comment: I've made a pic of the web.xml code because here says the code is not indented properly (WTF).

Also tried moving the xml file in the Web-Inf folder still no success

Comment: Can you post your tomcat log? It can be found on console tab.

Answer (score 1):

Your app is not deployed to the Tomcat as there is no log record such as

```
Deployment of web application directory ... ServletTutorial
```

As you configured eclipse to use tomcat installation try to check tomcat's webapp folder - there should be ServletTutorial directory with your app files. Check its integrity according to the tutorial. If it is not there, remove the app and add it again or do a full re-publish using Clean menu option in the Servers window.

I'd recommend do not mess with tomcat installation dir but configure it to use workspace metadata folder. Then only your app will be started withour manager, examples, and other unnecessary apps decreasing your develpoment cycle time.

Comment: I've deleted the server and created and new one, now it works!

So the tutorial I was following is wrong because you said the web.xml file must be in the WEB-INF folder and not in the Web-Content with the index.html, right?

Furthermore, even when the app working, I've checked in Tomcat/webapps and there is no Servlet Tutorial directory. 

Why is that?

Comment: That's because the new server is configured to use .metadata folder, not webapps directory. You can find your app somewhere near `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps`

Comment: I've noticed that each time I add a new java class I have to delete and recreate the server otherwise I get the resource not found error. Why is that? Anyway this issue can be avoided without having to delete and recreate the server all the times?

Answer (score 0):

nowadays (java ee 2019-09) the web.xml file is in the Tomcat folder, check if it has by default the same file name:

[image: like this] .